# Why is that the wider the aperture of a lens is, the more we can see through narrow cracks and crevices?

Tags: lens, aperture, focus

Example I took at 85mm f/1.4 on APS-C sensor:

[image]

Comment: Do these two pictures are taken from the same exact point?

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes a picture, even a crudely drawn one, is worth a thousand words.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That is not entirely true:

You can see better through them because the depth of field (DOF) is shallower. If you focus on the object behind, a wider aperture allows the foreground to be blurred more heavily:

[image]

<sup>Legend: BG ... background; FG ... foreground. 
Photos were made handheld (so framing and focus might nit be 100% accurate), no post-production (except crop and resize). 
All photos made at 105mm.</sup>

While the sample with the most blurred slats (the first) almost diminishes them, the overall scene became somewhat **darker** where the blur appears.

Comment: Nice observation, but it doesn't really answer the question about *why* this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The "entrance pupil" is the open aperture you are seeing from the front lens, basically with the diameter f:n (f being the focal length and n being the aperture number).  This is basically a disk, every point of which is looking out at any imaged point in the world.  The larger this disk is, the more angles are there from which this disk gets a peep at the world.  Basically you can draw a cone from the edge of this disk to any point in in-focus distance, and this cone (or its continuation) is how light arrives in the camera for each point on the sensor corresponing to the cone to its in-focus point in the focusing distance.  The more an object is out-of-focus, the less is its contribution to any particular cone and the more cones it contributes to.  To block an in-focus object point entirely from view, you need to block its entire cone to the entrance pupil.  With a large aperture and a close blocking object, only solid objects will do the trick.